# Tahanun on Superbowl Sunday in competing market?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is one supposed to recite תחנון on Superbowl Sunday if he is in the market of a team that is competing? What if it's a multi-team market, like the Jets and the Giants or the Redskins and the Ravens, and you don't support the team that made it?  What if you *do* support the team that made it, but you're in the wrong segment of the market?  What if you support *neither* team, but you live in the market among those who support the team (or vice versa)?  What if you're just visiting?  I assume מנהג המקום and מנהג אבותיכם are in conflict here, but which one wins (no pun intended of course - this is a *serious* question)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Aww, @isaacmoses, why??

Comment: Quoth http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated, "All Purim Torah questions must include the following disclaimer code at the bottom." By strictly adhering to the policy, we can go a little nuts while ensuring that things won't get out of hand.

Comment: Important side question: What are the statistics on when Superbowl Sunday will coincide with Purim? Actually, given that it always follows the 'ibur any time there is one, I think it can never coincide with a date in early February. However, Purim Katan probably can.

Comment: Can we legally say the name of El Plata Grande on this site?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, sounds like a decent question, IMHO. Maybe we should ask [Jonathan Mizrahi](https://sites.google.com/site/mizrahijonathan/home/ThanksgivingAndHanukkah).

Comment: @HodofHod, dunno. That's a [question for Meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). However, you do raise another good question. Can you mention it _Halachically_?

Comment: @SethJ I cannot think of any Talmudic discussions on trademark law. :)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, what if someone were to (**ahem**) [take things into his own hands](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/797/edit)? Not that I would ever...

Comment: @IsaacMoses According to [this site](http://stevemorse.org/jcal/whendid.html) Purim and Superbowl Sunday have never and will never overlap until they change the date of the Superbowl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- On Superbowl Sunday itself, supporters of both teams should say [Tachanun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachanun#Days_on_which_Tachanun_is_omitted) as well as [Selichot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selichot#Selichot_of_Fast_Days), as we do on the date of the war - [13 Adar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_of_Esther).<sup>1</sup>
- On the day after Superbowl Sunday, supporters of the winning team, wherever they live, will probably sleep through Shacharit. If they make it in time for Tachanun, they should skip it, as we do on the date of the celebration after the war - [14 Adar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim).
- [No Superbowl](http://cerritos.patch.com/articles/5-fun-super-bowl-facts-you-should-know-new-england-patriots-new-york-giants-eli-manning-tom-brady-nfl-overtime-rules-xlvi) has ever gone into overtime. If one ever does, then supporters of the winning team who live in cities that have football stadiums that were [domed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_National_Football_League_stadiums#Key) since the time of [Roger Staubach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XII) are entitled to sleep through Monday entirely and skip Tachanun on Tuesday.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1. As Superbowl Sunday always falls out on a Sunday, there's no issue of pushing it off for Shabbat.</sup>

<sup>2. If that Tuesday happens to be Mardi Gras, that'll be the headache of the posekim of that generation.</sup>

Comment: Do those who play their home games in domed stadiums celebrate on Tuesday?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, ooh, that's even better. Editing ...

Answer (score 7):

http://www.koltorah.org/Volume%2013/Kol%20Jachter.htm

> Do We Say Tachanun on Super Bowl Sunday? Of course not!  A Chassidic
>   Rabbi was asked this same question.  He responded, “Of course we would
>   not say Tachanun on Super Bowl Sunday!”  His disciples asked him,
>   “Don’t you believe that one is not allowed to watch television?”  This
>   issue has still not been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

We saw in the [haftarah of Yisro](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1006.htm#6):

> ו  וַיָּעָף אֵלַי, אֶחָד מִן-הַשְּׂרָפִים, וּבְיָדוֹ, רִצְפָּה; בְּמֶלְקַחַיִם--לָקַח, מֵעַל הַמִּזְבֵּחַ.
>
> ז  וַיַּגַּע עַל-פִּי--וַיֹּאמֶר, הִנֵּה נָגַע זֶה עַל-שְׂפָתֶיךָ; וְסָר עֲו‍ֹנֶךָ, וְחַטָּאתְךָ תְּכֻפָּר.
>
> 6 And one of the serafim flew onto me and in his hand was a floor...
>
> 7 ...and he said, "This touched your mouth." And your sin will disappear and your sin will be atoned.

In other words, his mouth touched the floor. The floor is down. So he made a touchdown.

But although he made a touchdown, the angel tells him that his sin is forgiven. How is this possible? It must be that he had said tachanun even though he made a touchdown.

Comment: I don't think this is a good proof. The reason that on happy days we don't say tachanun is because the simcha of the day accomplishes the forgiveness even without tachnun. Hence it is possible that the joy of the touchdown was what achieved the forgiveness and he didn't say tachanun.

Comment: I think I'm with @michoel on this. Besides, he could have scored the touchdown in any game, Lav Davka the Super Bowl. Tzarich 'Iyun.